# Фриланс на Java

Tags: работа, java

Подскажите насколько актуален фриланс **или** удаленная работа на Java?
Если да - то какие **области применения и технологии** Java, в этом плане наиболее перспективны?

Comment: фриланс - немного отличается. что ты подразумеваешь под ним?

Comment: Под фрилансом я подразумеваю выполнение разовых небольших проектов, удаленная работа - работа на долговременной основе через интернет.

Comment: @Natr, думаю, вам будет интересна [эта тема](http://hashcode.ru/questions/142773)

Comment: Спасибо Sleeping Owl - относительно технологий более или менее понятно. А актуальность фриланса или удаленки, как?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO:Наиболее простой и более перспективный путь в фрилансе - это Адроид-программирование. На Андроид-приложения спрос растет, соответственно будет и работа. А дальше можно подтянуть web и будешь незаменимый Java-программист.